# Summation of a sequence when sum of previous terms is inside sigma

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, summation-method

In the following summation, I need the current sum to be a part of the computation in the actual sigma, represented as,

$$a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n {[a_{n-1}(i+1) + i]}$$

for example, 
        $$a_1 = \sum_{i=1}^1 {[a_{0}(i+1) + i]}$$

and, $$a_2 = \sum_{i=1}^2 {[a_{1}(i+1) + i]}$$ $$...$$ $$...$$

I need the answer to be in terms of $a_0$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

there are a few simplifications we can make:
$$S=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[a_{n-1}(i+1)+i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^na_{n-1}(i+1)+\sum_{i=1}^ni$$
$$=a_{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)+\sum_{i=1}^ni$$
$$a_n=\frac{n(n+3)}{2}a_{n-1}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

EDIT 1:

If we looks at the formulas for each of the following terms we could try and estimate how it follows $a_0$:
[image: Coefficients]

This chart shows the iteration its is in column 1 (i.e. $a_1$,$a_2$ etc.), the coefficient of $a_0$ in column two and the added second part in the third column. For example, $a_8=1047816000a_0+917080508$. This appears to follow a near-exponential pattern so if many more terms were calculated a fairly accurate formula could be made, although I have one other idea.

EDIT 2:

If you could find a way of generating a general formula for a $a_{n+k}$ and prove this is true, then you could work back and find a formula for $a_n$. We can start by saying:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)(n+4)}{2}a_n+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+3)(n+4)}{2^2}a_{n-1}+\frac{n(n+1)^2(n+4)}{2^2}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

A similar example of a case is the Fibonacci sequence, which can be simplified as follows:
$$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$$
$$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-(-\varphi)^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: can we reach to an answer which is in terms of $a_0$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, but I have seen problems of this form be solved

Comment: This question can be expressed by a differential equation, all working provided by @kccu here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3216503/summation-dependent-on-previous-term/3216546#3216546

Comment: Where is the pattern you found

Comment: After doing a bit of calculations, i.e. putting values of $a_{k-1}$ into $a_k$ , i found a pattern , which can be formulated as: $$ a_n = k*a_2 + k - 1 $$  where ,$$n>2$$ and $$k = (n+1)! / 6$$ Can this be represented formally?

Comment: That looks good to me, if it works