# summation dependent on previous term

Tags: summation

In answering a question myself I have ended up with a summation of the form:
$$a_n=\frac{n(n+3)}{2}a_{n-1}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
I am unsure of how to solve this type of summation such that I have it in the form:
$$a_n=f(a_0,n)$$
I know that problems of this form can be solved as I have seen it in the Fibonacci sequences and other cases but I am not sure how I go about doing this, I will link the original question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215725/summation-of-a-sequence-when-sum-of-previous-terms-is-inside-sigma/3215762#3215762). Thanks!

Evidence of my attempt so far and how I got in this form can be found at the original question

EDIT:

I've found a formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) which talks about how to solve first order non-homogeneous recurrence relations, which states for a series in the form:
$$a_{n+1}-f_na_n=g_n$$
we can say:
$$a_n=\left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}f_k\right)\left(A_0+\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{g_m}{\prod_{k=0}^mf_k}\right)$$
So I will try to use this

Comment: Do you know about generating functions?

Comment: Not really no, although by searching it, it seems it could be used to solve problems of this form

Comment: Yes, that would be my approach.

Comment: Is there a way you could explain how to apply it when it is in this form? I can't find an example where $a_{n-1}$ is multiplied by a function of $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. Your recurrence can be re-written as:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)(n+4)}{2}a_n + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}a_n + (n+1)a_n + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}.$$
Now we multiply through by $x^n$ and sum from $n=0$ to $\infty$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)a_nx^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_nx^n + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)x^n\\
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^{n+1}&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)a_nx^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_nx^n + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(n+2)x^n\\
\frac{1}{x}(A(x)-a_0)&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}A(x) + \frac{d}{dx}A(x) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \Bigg(\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n}_{\frac{1}{1-x}}\Bigg)\\
\frac{1}{x}(A(x)-a_0)&= \frac{1}{2} A''(x) + A'(x) + \frac{1}{(1-x)^3}.
\end{align*}
So now you would need to solve this second-order non-homogeneous differential equation.

Comment: That is great, thank you!